# Алгоритм, склоняющий ФИО

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть алгоритм, склоняющий ФИО. Алгоритм не выдает ошибки на хостинге, но выдает ошибки на локальной машине, даже с новой версией вед сервера. Охота часть кода переписать, за этим и обращаюсь.

```
function rule ($rule) {
    preg_match("/^\s*([fm]?)\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$/", $rule, $m);
        if ( $m ) return array (
        "sex" => $m[1],
        "test" => split(',', $m[2]),
        "mods" => array ($m[3], $m[4], $m[5], $m[6], $m[7])
    );
    return false;
}
```

Ошибка:

> `Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in ...\skl.php on line 172`

Эта строчка появляется раз так 40. Могу показать весь код, но хотелось бы переписать данный кусок, ошибка на строчке

```
"test" => split(',', $m[2]),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте explode().
Синтаксис тот же.

есть еще `str_split($string,$piece_length)`, но вам нужен экспоуд

P.S. впрочем, есть более новый заменитель имеено вашей функции. Называется она

```
preg_split()
```

Но в данном случае, когда разбивка идет по одной запятой, регулярные выражения явно не нужны.

Comment: Синтаксис не тот же. `split` принимает регэксп, `explode` принимает строку.

Comment: Тот же в данном случае. =)

Comment: Warning: preg_split() [function.preg-split]: No ending delimiter ',' found in ...\skl.php on line 172

заменил на preg_split(). опять то же. на локальной машине ошибка. на хостинге тоже  8(

Comment: explode - сработало. огромное спасибо

Comment: Я так и написал, что ее хватит более чем.

Answer (score 2):

Замените `split` на `preg_split`. Это не ошибка. Оно ж вам ясно объясняет — функция объявлена deprecated.

Comment: Да, дада.. оно самое.

Answer (score 0):

после всего выше сказанного, возникла одна маленькая неприятность, иногда на месте получившейся ФИО, выводится ошибка "Cannot parse supplied name". что это может быть?

или

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (? or (?- at offset 2 in ...\skl.php on line 134

if (!isset($firstName)) {
        preg_match("/^\s*(\S+)(\s+(\S+)(\s+(\S+))?)?\s*$/", $lastName, $m);
        if(!$m) exit("Cannot parse supplied name");
        if($m[5] && preg_match("/(ич|на)$/",$m[3]) && !preg_match("/(ич|на)$/",$m[5])) {
            // ошибка на строчку выше
            $lastName = $m[5];
            $firstName = $m[1];
            $middleName = $m[3];
            $this -> fullNameSurnameLast = true;
        } else {
            // Сидоров Иван Петрович
            $lastName = $m[1];
            $firstName = $m[3];
            $middleName = $m[5];
        }
```

Comment: Сравните чем это имя отличается от остальных. Возможно, отсутствием или недостатком слов/запятых?

Comment: было: Иванов Иван Иванович

Comment: у меня аналогичный алгоритм (выдернул из какого то сайта). такое бывает если значение не передается. просто нужно дописать проверку.